# Unable to understand the syntax for iloc for reversing all rows vs reversing all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm unable to bring my head around the syntax used for reversing all rows vs reversing all columns in Pandas.

```
1. Reversing all rows : df.iloc[::-1]
2. Reversing all columns : df.iloc[:,::-1]
```

On a related note, what would be the way to reverse both rows and columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On a related note, what would be the way to reverse both rows and columns?

```
df.iloc[::-1, ::-1]
```

I think for explain slicing is best check how working it in [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation), here is used exactly same principe:

```
a[::-1]    # all items in the array, reversed
a[1::-1]   # the first two items, reversed
a[:-3:-1]  # the last two items, reversed
a[-3::-1]  # everything except the last two items, reversed
```

**Pandas rows**:

```
df.iloc[::-1]    # all items in the array, reversed
df.iloc[1::-1]   # the first two items, reversed
df.iloc[:-3:-1]  # the last two items, reversed
df.iloc[-3::-1]  # everything except the last two items, reversed
```

Btw, it is same like slice rows, get all columns with `:`, but obviously omited, because working same:

```
df.iloc[::-1]
df.iloc[::-1, :]
....
```

**Pandas columns** - first `:` means get all rows, then slice columns

```
df.iloc[:, ::-1]    # all items in the array, reversed
df.iloc[:, 1::-1]   # the first two items, reversed
df.iloc[:, :-3:-1]  # the last two items, reversed
df.iloc[:, -3::-1]  # everything except the last two items, reversed
```

Comment: Hey, works perfectly. Can you explain me the format as well. What my understanding was a simple : means to select everything from start to end. In case we want to specific the skip level as well ( -1 in this case ), we add another colon, is it?